# Problem with stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've made the following procedure:

```
/*Stored procedure*/
 create procedure SP_getlagerstatus(in Kategori VARCHAR(15), in minverdi int(3))
 select * from deler join delekategori on deler.DelekategoriID=delekategori.DeleKategoriID
 where DeleKategoriNavn ='Kategori' and Lagerstatus > 'minverdi';
```

when i run it with `call SP_getlagerstatus('biler',1);`I dont get any results, but when I run query directly as:

```
select * from deler join delekategori on deler.DelekategoriID=delekategori.DeleKategoriID
 where DeleKategoriNavn ='biler' and Lagerstatus > 1;
```

I get the desired result. What am I missing?

/Andy.l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omit the `'` around the parameters

```
 select * from deler join delekategori on deler.DelekategoriID=delekategori.DeleKategoriID
 where DeleKategoriNavn =Kategori and Lagerstatus > minverdi;
```